# Preview MSOffice files in .NET WPF app via OpenOffice/LibreOffice

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-office, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I want to implement MSOffice documents (doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx) viewer in WPF app, and do it without MSOffice installed on client machine.
From what I've learned, OpenOffice or LibreOffice SDK might be helpful, because both of this products support needed formats.
But I can't find any information about components (in both SDK's documentations) which would allow me to render and display source documents, while keeping formatting and styles.

Is there any at all? Or I just trying to solve this problem in the wrong way? Please help, and thanks in advance.

P.S. I actually found an [article](http://habrahabr.ru/post/49373/) (it's in russian) that explains how to use OpenOffice SDK with .NET, but, ofcourse, it doesn't solves the problem

P.P.S I saw lot of commercial solutions for .NET like groupdocs, aspose, etc., but there is no way I can use them, as long as they stay proprietary products

Comment: I would recommend to look for helper libraries instead of tackling OpenOffice directly. For spreadsheets you have ClosedXml (http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) and EPPlus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I'm afraid that non of this components allow me to display spreadsheets. Instead, they are aimed to create, edit and save spreadsheets.

Comment: Microsoft provides free viewers for all their office software.  Have you looked into installing the viewers on the client machines, and having your app call the viewer software?

Comment: I thought about this option as well, but I didn't installed any viewers yet, because I have no idea how I can integrate viewers into my app. I need to show document content inside window of my app, not separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any open source solutions, but DevExpress has controls that can render Excel spreadsheets, PDFs and Word documents, like this: https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor/